# Implementing jQuery plugin in React

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, plugins, import

I know this is a dirty work but i have to do it. I am having a plugin which i bought on a website and cannot implement it in my React app. I have the files placed in my src/assets/vendor/pluginFolder which are

**jquery.plugin.min.js 

jquery.plugin.min.css**

I have a react app where i try to use the plugin and i do it inside **componentDidMount()**

At the top i am initializing jquery like so

```
import $ from 'jquery';
```

I know this is not the best practice. Some say it is better to script link in the index.html but i did that as well and getting the same result.

Now where i am strugling is when i try to initialize the element

```
componentDidMount() {
        this.$el = $(this.el);
        this.$el.fileuploader($.extend(this.state.options, {
            enableApi: true
        }));
        this.api = $.fileuploader.getInstance(this.$el);
    };
```

I am getting the error

```
this.$el.pluginName is not a function
```

When i import the plugin at the top like this "Which is not installed with npm though"

```
require('../pluginPath/pluginName/Plugin.js')
```

I am getting tons of compilation errors which look something like this

```
./src/assets/vendor/pluginName/jquery.pluginName.min.js
  Line 7:4:      Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 7:57:     'define' is not defined                                                no-undef
  Line 7:68:     'define' is not defined                                                no-undef
  Line 7:155:    'jQuery' is not defined                                                no-undef
  Line 7:189:    Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 7:937:    Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  Line 7:2228:   Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
```

Anyone can help me with this?

Thanks

Comment: Put a `<script>` for jQuery and the plugin in your index.html's `<head>`. Next, add `/* global $ */` to your component. Now try to call the plugin function in your component. (the problem with your code as far as I can tell is that the plugin never attaches itself to `$` because its script never runs at all; requiring the plugin script won't work because it's not a JS module, it's a "normal" script)

Comment: Yes, from the errors im getting ... i guess that too ... the plugin cannot attach to $ for some reason. I tried adding global $ to the top of the component where im trying to call the plugin but still getting this.$el.pluginname is not a function